# How to solve this specific situation in 2048?

Tags: board-games, 2048-game

In trying to develop and perfect my strategies, I've been playing [2048-undo](https://www.quaxio.com/2048/).

This is what I got myself into:

[image: 2048 board with 4096 on top right and tiles 2048, 1024, 512, 2x256, 128, 64, 32, 8, 4, 3x2 and an inconveniently-placed 4.]

Since this is not an uncommon situation and I still don't know how to properly get out of it, I figured I'd ask here.

If at all possible, what I want the most is to merge my two `256` tiles which in turn would be merged with the `512` tile and then merge with `1024`, `2048` and then it should be easy enough to merge the two `4096` tiles.

But the two `256` tiles are separated by a `512` tile, and the truth is, I still haven't managed to learn **how to merge two tiles when there is one in between**.

Can it be accomplished? What does the general logic look like?

(please assume this is the traditional [2048](https://play2048.co/) game, made by Gabriele Cirulli with inspiration from other games - see page - and *not* the *undo* version).

Comment: I think you should make a new 128 with the 2s, 4, 8, 32, and 64 and merge it with the other 128 because if one is in between, I don't see them getting together especially with this much of a cramped board. I think you should make more space available first.

Comment: In general, you don't get to take pieces out from in between: playing a "left" at any point would mess your big tile order. (That's to say, the 4 under the 4096 is probably going to be a problem, and it probably got there because you played a left at some point.) If you absolutely can't avoid having a smaller tile in your big tile chain, you'll want to grow that one up until it becomes big enough to be in that spot.

Comment: Given that the next generated tile can be 2 or 4 and can be generated in any space, how would one solve a problem like this?